# What kind of shoes are best for wedding photography?

Tags: wedding

I'm an amateur photographer that loves portraits and recently I started to take photographs at weddings. As time goes by I'm getting more and more work to photograph these weddings.

The wedding party moves around almost the entire day, forcing me on my feet to run/walk/jog around to capture the images. After a full day of shooting my feet are often sore and hurting.

From my point of view, a good pair of shoes should be professional looking but also function so that my feet are not sore or hurting. This would allow me to keep on my feet instead of sitting to get the next shot at the wedding.

Comment: I am super-amused that while you are _clearly_ trolling in response to the [earplugs question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41801/1943), you got several serious answers that actually might be helpful to someone. So now I'm inclined to vote to leave _both_ of 'em open.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about photography.

Comment: specialise in beach weddings and go barefoot :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has absolutely nothing to do with photography.

Comment: @Tetsujin I couldn’t agree more. The community seems to like this question. I submitted it to show my distaste for a similar question linked to in an above comment.

Comment: "I couldn’t agree more." ... as evidenced by your VtC _your own question_ 2 hours after asking it. lol! =)

Comment: I posted an answer stating  "your gunna need a quality shoe". A song by Mark Knopfler, Quality Shoe.  Somebody stuck there nose in  and deleted it. ( BOO ) It is technically an answer ( all be it short and sweet with a  link to the songs video, )  and **GOOD advise**.  **Really? can we not have a little fun here?**

Answer (score 9):

I wear Bostonian dress Flexlite shoes when I am working conferences and trade shows. I am on my feet 16+ hours a day, and could not do it without these shoes. They are comfortable and very supportive. They look like dress shoes (well they are dress shoes), but they feel and fit like running shoes. The soles are rubber, and several styles are available. Highly recommended.

[image]

http://bostonian.clarksusa.com/eng/search/advanced/?keywords=flexlite

Comment: Can't believe I just gave fashion advice. Can't believe I gave fashion advice on a photography website either.

Comment: I use a similar shoe (Clarks CDX) and I find them quite noisy on stone floors like in quiet churches and distracts the guests.  Is that something you get too or do I need to break them in a bit more?

Comment: Can't say I have noticed, the soles are fairly soft, but don't look like a rubber sole, they look very leather like from a distance

Comment: Real fashion advice would include the proper camera and lens combo to match the shoes.

Comment: @Rene, you can never go wrong with black. Thinking about putting a thin red pinstripe on my shoes to match ;)

Comment: It's the camera bag that needs to match the shoes, not the camera itself. But... because black goes with everything, you should blacken all labels and such on the camera and lenses.

Comment: I like my Roper-style cowboy boots. I have a black pair on order to use with my tux :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm glad to answer your question and I hope will helpful for you. 
I'm a wedding photographer from Brazil, here we have lot's of confortable brands of shoes, as in your country has.
If you're shooting the cerimony you must use social shoes, and that's why I prefer invest on great socks instead of classic socks (you're not going to sit down, so this wont be a problem).
If you're shooting outside photos or party photos I recomend mizuno or another jog tennis and if you're shooting trash the dress
that you probably will get your shoe dirty, I recommend Timberland or another boot.

Comment: Great suggestion about the socks.  I forgot about that detail in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Im a vain type of guy, working with research, consulting and development, so I often wear a dress jacket or full suit at work and shoes to match. I also bike every day to and from work, and go to machine halls to review automation solutions and my own machine vision solutions. I also live in Denmark where it always rains. This gives me experience with how to dress cool while being practical.

I suggest you look into Clarks and Echo shoes. They make comfy dressy stuff, even with goretex (maybe not so relevant for you). I also have stuff like Timberland and Lloyds. Timberland is a bit to rudged to pass as dress shoes, but they are very comfy (there might be models that would work) and Lloyds are great but not too comfy, and I only wear them if I am certain it wont rain.

If you want the opposite ditch, Hagloefs is a trekking brand that has a few models that doesnt look too silly with dress clothes, but they definitely look apart, but it would be max comfort. They have been taken over by Asics, which may have ruined it for them, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of either Dockers or Sketcher's dress shoes.  Add a pair of gel inserts if you need and that should help a lot.  Also, use of a monopod and any good weight balancing gear you can use will also help spread the weight out evenly.  As edilsonfb pointed out, using really good socks can also help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_stockings

Answer (score 1):

Two words are all you need to know: *Dr. Scholl's*

[http://www.amazon.com/Dr-Scholls-Mens-Oren-Lace-Up/dp/B005QLOXOC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005QLOXOC)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but probably you can consult an orthopedist.

It is not necessary that you have a problem, but he could make you a specific molded shoe so it perfectly fits your feet.

Just an Idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answers were specific for men's shoes so far.  What may well work either way are ballroom dancing shoes.  The soles are usually suede which may or may not be a problem but obviously they are made for looking well and being reasonably comfortable to move around in.  Latin dancing shoes may also be an option, particularly for women (where they tend to be of the sandalette with heels kind).