# Why do professional printers still feature cartridges?

Tags: printing, ink-jet

I am considering printing my own wall-calendars, this would mean volumes of around 700 pages. Understandable I would burn through many ink-cartridges*.

Currently there are 2 types of Ink-Jet printers:

- Cartridge based
- Refillable Ink-tank based.

The latter is cheaper by a third or fourth in almost every case. I would like to thus ask the seasoned photogs, printers, why is it that professional printers are not moving away from the cartridge system yet?

*Doing it professionally is not within the scope of this question.

Comment: I'm afraid this has nothing to do with photography => totally offtopic.

Comment: If this was a question asking about developer for printing a film negative would it be relevant for a photography site? I think in the digital workflow printing questions are still relevant to the modern photographer who wants to do something more with their imagery than hoard them on their hard drive.

Comment: *"... why is it that professional printers are not moving away from the cartridge system yet?"* Some would say that the truly professional printers (that is, businesses that are paid to print things) have never used cartridges.

Comment: @walther i said the same thing about another printer based question the other day but as a printer is considered photographic hardware it can be argued it's on topic.

Comment: Here's my reasoning for calling this on-topic — as well as the infamous one about [what shoes to wear](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/). We want this site to have a community of users interested in photography — the art and process of making images with light. When the question is about a topic related to that process and practice even when it's not about cameras, it helps build up the community of people with that interest. Conversely, when a topic is about using cameras but _not for photography_, that's better on a site centered around that different interest.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Printing our pictures, for personal or commercial purposes is a level of quality every photographer aspires to. I don't see how this could be deemed off-topic. Photographic printing is not comparable to normal printing. The complexity of calibrating printers, monitors, color gamuts, paper types, lamination types- is not something anyone outside this forum is likely to know about.

Comment: I feel i may understand why some see this as off-topic. On the face of it, it seems to be a question about printers, and we're here for photography. *however* This question has to do with the business side of photography, it isn't about printers, but how printers affect our costs as photographers.

Answer (score 1):

The cynic in me would say it's the Xerox business model.
Sell the printers cheap, make money on the ink.

If it's not a sealed & chip-protected system, you can use any ink you like - therefore, they lose money to whoever can sell the cheapest ink.

Slightly away from topic - laser printers are now sold with half-filled cartridges to alleviate the issue where it was becoming cheaper to buy a new machine than change the ink.

Comment: It's not just Xerox, the "sell the printer at a loss to tie the consumer into ink at inflated prices" model is a reality that was confirmed to a relative by an employee at one of the other manufacturers years ago.

Comment: Sure. I only meant Xerox was the first accepted model that worked that way. They all seem to do it now, whether admitting openly to it or not. It's a sensible business model.

Comment: Long before Xerox there were the safety razor manufacturers that sold, at a loss, handles for holding their razor blades which were incredibly profitable.

Comment: No doubt even that wasn't a first. I imagine at one point there was cheap stabling for horses, with expensive hay - the price painted over the door looks good, the bill when you leave is higher ;)

Comment: Sound logic until you consider that cheap inks destroy nozzles and your average semi-pro photog cannot buy a second professional photo-printer.

Comment: Someone will always be tempted to buy the cheap stuff, no matter what the end result. I tried it myself, back in my crappy consumer-level inkjet days. cheap inks, syringes, "chippers" to try bypass the security measures. All a total waste of time & money, but I was drawn to it.